# LaTeX Error: Environment pandoccrossrefsubfigures undefined

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to render a Markdown document as PDF using pandoc. It includes subfigures and cross-references. When producing the PDF, I get this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment pandoccrossrefsubfigures undefined.
```

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7, pandoc 2.14.1, and pandoc-crossref.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is perfectly described in the error message: the environment `pandoccrossrefsubfigures` doesn't exist, and this prevents the creation of the PDF file.

To solve the problem, just create a new, known environment to replace the missing one:

```
\newenvironment{pandoccrossrefsubfigures}
{
  \begin{figure}
}
{
  \end{figure}
}
```

As a result, the environment named `pandoccrossrefsubfigures` will be replaced by one named `figure` that pandoc will recognize.

For more information about this problem, there is [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/issues/326) where pandoc-crossref's author explains the reasons behind this problem, and also provides multiple solutions.